# Creature to retrieve criminals and imprison them

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology

For my world I was thinking of there being a domesticated creature that is able to swallow humans whole and keep them in a second stomach which acts as a prison. I figured it would need to be tall and presumably a herbivore or omnivore and how would intelligence work for it. Would science be able to make it smart enough to understand orders of going off and bringing them back like a retriever dog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plausible reason why the creature keeps its victims alive in this stomach?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121591/what-is-a-plausible-reason-why-the-creature-keeps-its-victims-alive-in-this-stom)

Comment: no, this is different in that it acts as a retriever

Comment: Then I recommend that you remove all references to stomachs and focus on the retriever part.

Comment: will do, i'll edit it now

Comment: VTC retracted.  (And made the title match the body.)

Comment: Will one of the answers in that question work for you? Minus the digestion part in the second stomach.

Comment: Well actually I figured it would be a herbivore so if it did release stomach acid then it wouldn't be strong enough to digest the person

Comment: Also, you can reply to a comment by using the at symbol followed by their name. For example, I could reply to your comment with @AOS1981LeaderOfThe1981Arm or simply @ (without the space right here) AOS1981. If no one is specified, the person whose post you commented on gets the notification. Keep in mind that you can only mention 1 person in a comment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info i'm new here so i'm still figuring it out - @John Locke

Comment: @AOS1981 Got it :)

Comment: "*it wouldn't be strong enough to digest the person*".  I'm not sure that's a valid assumption.

Comment: I mean I figured it’s digestion would only be strong enough to digest grass leaving a Human strong enough to withstand it @RonJohn

Comment: Also, the `hard-science` tag is pretty strict: "
Requires answers **backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc.** Contrast with: science-based and reality-check tags."  An imaginary creature like you describe can't have any such answers.  You probably want `science-based` and/or `reality-check`.

Comment: Hint: don't answer your question ("I figured it would need to be tall and presumably a herbivore or omnivore") in the question.  Just ask the question.  (I know it's an easy trap to fall into, having done it myself so often.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try coming up with something akin to a marsupial type species from Earth. A kangaroo for example uses its pouch to to gestate young ones and suckle them, but also uses it as a way of protect Joey's that are fully capable to now live off external food sources and move around independently.

Maybe this herbivore has a pouch with an opening controllable via muscles and would operate similar to how a mouth would operate. It would be able to hold the pouch tight shut but also occasionally release air for better circulation .

I am guessing the herbivore should work in tandem with an officer . There needs to be some way to ensure that prisoners  are weapon free and are not trying to blast their way open, which would essentially kill the herbivore.

Modelling it on a kangaroo would also allow the use of hind legs for holding prisoners while they are being inserted into the pouch.

Comment: Excellent outside-the-box thinking!

Answer (score 3):

You can consider several ways aside from the stomach holding area since your prisoner can still probably move about in there and possibly cut their way open. Think along the lines of a spider trussing its victims up with sticky web and immobilizing them with some sort of venom or the web itself can act as a paralyzing agent.

The animal could be a bio-engineered animal with enhanced intelligence and prizes a certain food, say a synthetized honey/jelly concoction that it needs to survive or breed.

It would have to have an enhanced sense such as smell so they can track their prey and can be trained to sniff out and retrieve them in exchange for the food. This also gives your characters a way out in case your story requires it.

Other ways your animal can trap humans could be by sonics, stunning and rendering them unconscious. These could work with actual human hunters to capture the prey so they do not have to be very big and can be controlled by whistles or such other similar devices.

Comment: Oh thanks, this is actually pretty cool though I have a question, if the Spider had enhanced intelligence then wouldn't it be smart enough to leave its creators and then go and find a different food source for itself?

Comment: That's where the synthesized food comes in. Only humans from that agency, for example, can create it.